# Php Filtro Pesquisa Mysql

Tags: php, mysql

Tenho um banco de dados `MySQL` com varias tabelas. Nome delas abaixo:

- Tabela: `formacao`
- Tabela: `idiomas`
- Tabela: `usuarios`

Preciso de filtrar informações, exemplo:

A pessoa quer o candidato que seja pedreiro, que saiba inglês, que tenha 2º Grau.

- A informação de profissão, está na tabela `usuarios`.
- A informação de linguagem, está na tabela `idiomas`.
- A informação de escolaridade, está na tabela `formacao`

Eis minha dúvida. Como fazer uma busca que pegue várias tabelas?

Obs. Na tabela `usuarios` tem id e nas outras tem `idusuarios`, a informação que aparece no id aparece no `idusuarios`.

Estrutura da tabela `formacao`:

```
CREATE TABLE `formacao` (
`idusuarios` int(255) NOT NULL,
`idformacao` int(255) NOT NULL,
`graudeformacao` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
`cursotecnico` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
`cursofaculdade` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
`situacao` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
`dataconclusao` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
`dia` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
`mes` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
`ano` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
`nomeinstituicao` varchar(255) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Estrutura da tabela `idiomas`:

```
CREATE TABLE `idiomas` (
`idusuarios` int(255) NOT NULL,
`ididioma` int(255) NOT NULL,
`nomeidioma` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
`nivelidioma` varchar(100) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Estrutura da tabela `usuarios`:

```
CREATE TABLE `usuarios` (
`id` int(255) NOT NULL,
`numerocir` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
`validadecir` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
`numpassaporte` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
`passvencimento` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
`categoria` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
`nomecompleto` text NOT NULL,
`email` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
`cpf` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
`senha` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
`datanascimento` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
`estadocivil` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
`sexo` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
`altura` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
`peso` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
`numerodabota` varchar(20) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`nacionalidade` text NOT NULL,
`naturalidadeestado` text NOT NULL,
`naturalidadecidade` text NOT NULL,
`url` text NOT NULL,
`lembretedesenha` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
`fotorosto` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
`endcep` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
`endrua` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
`endnumero` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
`endcomplemento` text CHARACTER SET latin1 COLLATE latin1_general_ci NOT NULL,
`endbairro` text NOT NULL,
`endestado` text NOT NULL,
`endcidade` text NOT NULL,
`celular` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
`convencional` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
`convrecado` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
`convnomerecado` text NOT NULL,
`celrecado` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
`celnomerecado` text NOT NULL,
`numerodefilhos` varchar(20) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`fumante` varchar(20) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`idformacao` int(255) NOT NULL,
`idcursos` int(255) NOT NULL,
`idembarque` int(255) NOT NULL,
`idexperiencias` int(255) NOT NULL,
`ididiomas` int(255) NOT NULL,
`codigoadm` varchar(5) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`moderacao` int(2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`codigoconfirma` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
`confirmarcaoemail` int(5) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`reenvioemail` varchar(50) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
 `liberado` int(5) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0'
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Comment: Coloque a estrutura completa das tabelas, ajudará a formular uma resposta mais precisa

Comment: Precisamos ver a estrutura das tabelas e as relações entre si. De qualquer modo dê olha olhada no google sobre Inner Join.

Comment: Utilizando JOIN você consegue pegar informações em múltiplas tabelas. Data uma olhada neste artigo com exemplos em PHP.<br />
http://blog.thiagobelem.net/relacionamento-de-tabelas-no-mysql